# Jupyter command `jupyter-kernelspec` not found when intentando Kernes de Wolfram-Mathematica

Tags: kernel, jupyter, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to work with the Wolfrma-Mathematica Kernes in Jupyter but when executing
**./configure-jupyter.wls **add produce **Jupyter command `jupyter-kernelspec` not found.   **

```
root@Lenovo-G50-45:/home/laptop/Documentos/Anton_Lap/1unitec/Practicarios_UNUTEC/WolframLanguageForJupyter-master# ./configure-jupyter.wls add
configure-jupyter.wls: An error has occurred. The desired Wolfram Engine is not in "jupyter kernelspec list."
configure-jupyter.wls: See below for the message that Jupyter returned when attempting to add the Wolfram Engine.
usage: jupyter [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir]
               [--paths] [--json] [--debug]
               [subcommand]

Jupyter: Interactive Computing

positional arguments:
  subcommand     the subcommand to launch

options:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --version      show the versions of core jupyter packages and exit
  --config-dir   show Jupyter config dir
  --data-dir     show Jupyter data dir
  --runtime-dir  show Jupyter runtime dir
  --paths        show all Jupyter paths. Add --json for machine-readable
                 format.
  --json         output paths as machine-readable json
  --debug        output debug information about paths

Available subcommands: bundlerextension execute migrate nbextension notebook
serverextension troubleshoot

Jupyter command `jupyter-kernelspec` not found.
```